# What is the MLB record for most errors by one team in one season during the modern era?

Tags: statistics, mlb

What is the MLB record for most errors by one team in one season during the modern era?

Comment: Are you looking for the record for the most errors or the least errors?

Comment: Most errors, in modern era.  Thanks for the clarification question.

Answer (score 3):

Sporting News record book suggests:

867 by Washington in 1886 (122 games)

If you only want after 1900 then

425 by Detroit in 1901 (136 games)

According to baseball-reference.com, since 2000, the leagues (with 30 teams) have never recorded more than 3500 errors.  Between 1901 and 1917 the leagues  (with only 16 teams) never recorded less than 3500 errors.

For more information, root around on baseball-reference.com.  I don't know of a perfect summary, but you can see team fielding stats for every individual year.  As an example, to see team stats for 2014, go to http://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2014-standard-fielding.shtml

Comment: Thanks for that.  Is there a link I can use to check further, i.e., like maybe since 1950, or by league?  I couldn't find the info anywhere by various Google searches.